# How can I compile c++ on (64bit) windows to make a 64bit exe?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, 64-bit, g++

Using the g++ compiler that came with code::blocks I can compile 32bit programmes but when I try to compile to a 64bit programme it tells me that 64 bit isn't implemented, even though I have 64bit os.

How can I compile c++ to make a 64bit exe?

Comment: Get a compiler that produces 64 bit executables on Windows OS.

Comment: Having a 64-bit OS doesn't magically mean all your compilers suddenly output 64-bit code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download Microsoft Visual C++, and set the target to 64-bit.

Why make programming harder than it needs to be?

Comment: Yes. For express edition http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

Comment: @Kevinkeegan: [Note that Visual C++ Express doesn't include 64-bit tools by default. You'll also need to install the Windows SDK.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)

Comment: Visual C++ is windows only (down vote)
g++ is cross platform.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not limited to gcc, you can use Microsoft's compiler from Visual Studio Express 2010 with Windows SDK (both are free) and you can [configure Visual C++ Projects to Target 64-Bit Platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)

Comment: Are there any significant  differences between gcc and V.S express , that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Kevinkeegan: Both gcc (g++) and VS2010 are good compilers. I think gcc has better support for the latest language standards (C99, C++11) right now, although there is an improved VS11 coming in the near future. VS is a complete IDE/compiler/debugger and gcc is command-line only but there are several free IDEs available that support it.

Answer (score 2):

Download the 64-bit version of gcc, or recompile it yourself with 64-bit support.

I think [mingw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) comes with a version of gcc that can compile 64-bit binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Code:Blocks supports Visual Studio as the compiler, you can download it here http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express, also the fact you have a 64 bit OS has got nothing to do with whether you can compile 64 but code, it even has nothing to do with the CPU architecture, think about it, you can compile Android code in Linux, OSX and Windows and you are not running on an ARM CPU. The Code:Blocks page tells you how to configure it to use the MS compiler.

If you want the 64 bit compiler you need to install either the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279) or the [WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852361)